# What security measures should I apply to prevent downloading of my documents?

Tags: apache, security, watermark

I am with a project of a photographer. He got a lot of copyright images and want to show or preview them in a website with watermark over it. He also wants to enable download of good quality original picture without watermark of that picture to the members who paid for that specific images.

I am planning as following for preventing unauthorised download:
1.) placing all the images without the watermark in a secret folder and preventing access to its content using **.htaccess**
2.) to show image with watermark call it using preview.php file [read the file from secret file and add watermark and show it to browser]
3.) to enable download without watermark call it using download.php and inside download.php checking the credentials and if everything goes right with logged user then read the original file from secret location and output the content to browser.

Are there any other security measures that I should take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding a .htaccess file, just put the folder outside of your websites root directory. Other than that, sounds good.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing here sounds fine. I 'd probably put the photos entirely outside the webroot, but that shouldn't make a practical difference vs the `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a method thats often called "hotlink protection" whereby you block requests with HTTP referers that are not your own site. mod_rewrite is very good for this. Here is an example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```